# Liferay kaleo workflow notifications, send email to specific user not to role

Tags: java, xml, liferay, workflow

I'm using kaleo-workflow to manage the publish of web contents in my liferay portal.

I'm using the single approver workflow modified a little bit, just to define a role for the editor(the person who creates the content and submits it to the approver) and a role for the approver.
I want the reject notification to arrive only to the user who first submitted the web content for review, not to all the users of his role, is this possible via the workflow definition xml?

Answer (score 3):

Apologies as this is an extremely late response but you may be able to add this:

```
<recipients>
    <user />
</recipients>
```

inside the `<notification>` node, and below the `<notification-type>` node.
I believe the `<user />` tag refers to the person who created the asset. I haven't tested this but there is a similar notification definition in the single approver workflow under the "Review" `<task>` node.

See the Liferay documentation on [Creating Workflow Definitions](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/creating-new-workflow-definitions-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-11-en).